# If the measure on a measure space X is not $\sigma$-finite, does $X$ have infinite measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a measure space with measure $\mu$. Suppose that $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite, so that $X$ is not the countable union of measurable sets of finite measure. Does this imply that the measure of $X$ is infinite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, otherwise take $A_1:=X$ and $A_k=\emptyset$ for $k\geq 2$.

Actually, it seems reasonable that a finite measure space is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized it myself.

Answer (score 4):

If $X$ has finite measure then $X$ can be written as 
$$X=X \cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset \cup ...$$
which is a countable union of finite measure sets. Therefore $X$ would be $\sigma$-finite.